# C++ - Google Test - How to run all tests in different directories in parallel?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I am working on a C++ project with numerous test folders generated by Google test platform. For example after making the project, I will have the following executable test files, each containing multiple test suites:

```
/proj/build/interface/test/test1_executable
/proj/build/interface/test/test2_executable
/proj/build/module2/test/test1_executable
/proj/build/module2/test/test2_executable
```

I would like to run all tests after a new build. Is these a way to run all of these files at one once, hopefully in parallel?

Python has a utility called `nosetests` that can run of the tests in a project. How do C++ programmers run all tests in a project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like you are creating one binary per test. That is not how you should use googletest.

If you write a single [main function](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/primer.md#writing-the-main-function), you have a single binary with all tests. You can still select single tests by adding `--gtest_filter=whatever`.

Comment: I am create one binary file per module, and in each test file I have 2-3 unit test. Do I need to create only one main.cpp for the entire unit test?

Comment: That is what I would suggest, yes.

Answer (score 0):

"How do C++ programmers run all tests in a project?" - That depends entirely on the test framework and build system used. There is no standardized solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, create a batch file and prepend the word START to each line:

```
START /proj/build/interface/test/test1_executable
START /proj/build/interface/test/test2_executable
START /proj/build/module2/test/test1_executable
START /proj/build/module2/test/test2_executable
```

In Linux, append a & at the end of each line of the batch file:

```
/proj/build/interface/test/test1_executable&
/proj/build/interface/test/test2_executable&
/proj/build/module2/test/test1_executable&
/proj/build/module2/test/test2_executable&
```